# how can a list of references and imported modules be obtained from a .net C# exe or dll?

Tags: c#, .net, module, .net-assembly

Given any C# exe or dll, I would like to obtain a list of all the assemblies it references as well as all the imported modules. What's the simplest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have given answers for doing this programatically. If you just want to see a list though, you can use a decompiler like [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) from Telerik. Open the .dll with it, and you will be able to navigate the list of references etc on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to know how to get the reference assemblies. Please see the link below. I am not sure about your question regarding to imported modules please provide more details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx

Or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetDependentAssemblies` as below:

```
private IEnumerable<Assembly> GetDependentAssemblies(Assembly analyzedAssembly)
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => GetNamesOfAssembliesReferencedBy(a)
                            .Contains(analyzedAssembly.FullName));
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetNamesOfAssembliesReferencedBy(Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(assemblyName => assemblyName.FullName);
}
```

The `analyzedAssembly` parameter represents the assembly for which you want to find all the dependents.